# How to migrate to the latest ruby patch version

Tags: ruby, rvm

How to migrate to the latest ruby patch version (say from 1.9.3p286 to 1.9.3p362 or later)

Comment: Don't you mean ruby version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.9.3-p362 is current, but has some documented errors. 1.9.3-p327 is recommended until they issue a new release.

At that point, do:

- `rvm get latest`
- `rvm install 1.9.3` or `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

RVM will install the latest version if you don't specify the version number.

Per the documentation, `rvm reinstall` is equivalent to:

```
rvm remove  [ruby-string]
rvm install [ruby-string]
```